# Mongodb data to a nodeJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB which passes data onto a nodeJS file. The nodeJS has a function to add an item and then that redirects the user to another page. However I need the array which should be in the "product_cat" field within the Products collection.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to connect to server", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the server");
        var collection = db.collection('Products');
        //json record
        var nProduct = {
            Product: {
                Name: req.body.Name,
                Description: req.body.Description
            },
            product_cat: req.body.product_cat,
            product_price: req.body.product_price
        };
        console.log("Saving..", nProduct)
        collection.insertOne(nProduct, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Cannot write", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Saving..", nProduct)
                res.redirect("/Products")
            }

        });
        db.close();
    }
});
```